# Load drawables efficiently not using much memory

Tags: android, memory-management, out-of-memory

In my application I have a scrolling menu and I use this function to full menu items. But most of the time I am getting out of memory error. I don't get error in my emulator. But my device fails all the time.
I tried

```
   android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:largeHeap="true"
```

and reduced the images size too. But device says that it takes too much of memory. I want my app to be faster loading and memory efficient. I am still a starter in android. I saw some articles about loading images efficiently. But I didn't understand. Can anyone help me with some sample code?

```
public void RefreshMenuItems(int category) {
    //Create menu scroller
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams card_lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    card_lp.setMargins(dp(5), 0, dp(5), 0);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams image_lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0);
    image_lp.setMargins(dp(40), dp(5), dp(40), dp(5));
    image_lp.weight = 0.5f;

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams desc_lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0);
    desc_lp.weight = 0.32f;

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams title_lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0);
    title_lp.weight = 0.08f;

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams price_rp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    price_rp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams buy_rp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    buy_rp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams bottom_lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0);
    bottom_lp.weight = 0.1f;

    //fill menu
    for (int i = 0; i < item_title.length; i++) {
        final int currenti = i;

        if ((item_category[i] == category) || category == 0) {
            TextView title = new TextView(this);
            title.setText(item_title[currenti]);
            title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            title.setTextColor(0xff212121);
            title.setPadding(dp(10), dp(0), dp(10), dp(0));
            title.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            title.setLayoutParams(title_lp);
            title.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.borderradius2);
            title.setTextSize(fontpercent_screenheight(2.5));

            ImageView item = new ImageView(this);
            item.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(item_image[i], "drawable", getPackageName()));
            item.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            item.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            item.setLayoutParams(image_lp);

            TextView desc = new TextView(this);
            desc.setText(item_shortdesc[currenti]);
            desc.setPadding(dp(10), dp(5), dp(10), dp(5));
            desc.setLayoutParams(desc_lp);
            desc.setTextSize(fontpercent_screenheight(2.5));

            TextView price = new TextView(this);
            price.setText(String.format(sign + "%.2f", Double.parseDouble(item_price[currenti])));
            price.setPadding(0, dp(5), dp(10), dp(5));
            price.setLayoutParams(price_rp);
            price.setTextSize(fontpercent_screenheight(2.5));

            buy = new TextView(this);
            buy.setText(R.string.MenuAddToOrderButton);
            buy.setPadding(dp(10), dp(5), 0, dp(5));
            buy.setTextColor(0xffff0000);
            buy.setLayoutParams(buy_rp);
            buy.setTextSize(fontpercent_screenheight(2.5));
            buy.setClickable(true);
            buy.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    addItemToOrder(currenti);
                }
            });
            buy.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        ((TextView) v).setTextColor(0xff212121);
                    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        ((TextView) v).setTextColor(0xffff0000);
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });

            RelativeLayout bottom = new RelativeLayout(this);
            bottom.setLayoutParams(bottom_lp);
            bottom.addView(buy);
            bottom.addView(price);

            LinearLayout card = new LinearLayout(this);
            card.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            card.setLayoutParams(card_lp);
            card.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.borderradius1);
            card.setWeightSum(1f);
            card.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ItemProfile.class).putExtra("item_image", getResources().getIdentifier(item_image[currenti], "drawable", getPackageName())).putExtra("item_title", item_title[currenti]).putExtra("item_desc", item_desc[currenti]).putExtra("item_price", Double.parseDouble(item_price[currenti]));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            card.addView(title);
            card.addView(item);
            card.addView(desc);
            card.addView(bottom);

            menu.addView(card);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Any time I start to see looping over code that creates views by hand, I'm usually concerned that things are not being done in an optimal way. Take another look at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html. You may want to look into a ListView, it looks like you are attempting to build one by hand.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to build a menu, containing a list of menu items. A list should almost never be created in android by creating the Views yourself. You should use a ListView  and an adapter.

Comment: but how can I change this to an adapter ?

Comment: The documentation for creating listviews are fantastic. I suggest looking at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews.  Your "menu" will likely become a ListView, and your "card" will be an item displayed by your adapter inside your list.

Comment: Can also recommend that you take a look at recyclerViews. 
https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html
They can do what you are looking for farley easy

Comment: recyclerviews are possible in eclipse?

Comment: can you help me in converting this to a listview and adapter? I just have the basic idea of them..